# Is this a good practice? – Eloquent: Getting a table record from a specific column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to get an instance of an Eloquent model record based on a specific column that it is not the `pk`.

So in the controller I'm doing:

```
$object = Object::getByObjectName($objectName);
```

And in the `Object` model I have:

```
    public static function getByObjectName($objectName)
    {
        return self::where('object_name', $objectName)->first();
    }
```

Is this a good practice using `self::where` and it is a good practice the whole approach in general?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use where clause instead of going for this much trouble?

Comment: if you want to make a helper method for yourself it is fine ... you may want to look into the differences between `self` and `static` though just to be aware of them (`self::where...` vs `static::where...`)

Comment: No, I am suggesting to remove helper method completely. just use where clause in your controller, very simple.

Comment: As with anything it depends. Does it add any expressiveness or documentation as opposed to the where method? No. Does it reduce repetition? Maybe, if many of those calls were to be made throughout different locations in your program then maybe wrapping it in a method is nice. In case the attribute name would change you would only have to change the attribute's name inside your method and the program would still work. But if you were to only have a hand full of those calls it is not per se a need. (as on it's own the method provides no additional behaviour)

Comment: Like: Boat::where('boat_name', $boatName)->first();

Comment: How about `Boat::whereBoatName('some boat name')->first()` and you don't need to write any additional methods.

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour! Thats a nice one, I'm going with that one. Thank you!

Comment: Good points @Remy , Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do in the controller:

```php
public function getBoatByName($boatName){
   $boat = Boat::where('name', $boatName)->first();

}
```